# Unity's TiltShift Shader has Poor Visual Result on Mobile (Android)?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, glsl, shader

I have been trying to use Unity's TiltShift on Mobile and despite the result looks great on editor, it did not "work" on an Android device (HTC one M7). When the shader is applied on Android device, the result is basically indistinguishable as when the shader is not applied at all.

Original (shader not applied):

[image]

Shader applied on Editor:

[image]

Shader applied on Android Device:

[image]

Could someone kindly tell me why this is the case? I understand that some weaker GPU will not be able to handle some shader. But from what I know, if that is the case, the shader will be dropped and not used. I used logcat and have found no log like the following:

```
The image effect (<shader name here>) has been disabled as it's not supported on the current platform
```

So, it should indicate that the shader could be processed as the GPU can handle all the function calls. As such, shouldn't the shader produce the same result (or at least similar result), like the one on editor, on mobile as well?

I did use a smaller sample size for the TiltShift shader (Using the 12 one instead of the 28 one). But that still did not explain why the shader act so differently when on editor and on mobile.

I am very new to shader, please yell at me if I did something wrong. Thank you very much :)

I am using Unity 4.6 and that the screenshots are just a 3D cube + a screenshot of a game behind it.

Comment: I _think_ you can post images here as well.

Comment: I would like to, but I don't have 10 reputation to post images :)

Comment: I have 10 reputation now, thank you :) . I have also posted the images here now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need shader model 3 and depth texture support on a device for it to work on a device. For mobile devices shader model 3 is relatively new, as it came with OpenGL ES 3.0. Check this page for more:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-TiltShiftHdr.html. Its fairly strange that a mobile device as new as the HTC One wouldn't have it, but there you go.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation :D !